# Outline of a tag-like shape

Tags: html, css

I've made a tag-like shape in HTML/CSS as can be seen here - http://jsfiddle.net/RuXyP/

```
.tag {
float: left;
text-align: center;
height: 14px;
width: 110px;
background-color: #2e353d;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding-top: 2px;
margin-top: 1px;
font-size: 10px;
}
.arrow-right {
width: 0;
height: 0;
float: left;
margin-top: 1px;
border-top: 8px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
border-left: 8px solid #2e353d;
}
```

I'm attempting to add an outline to it and have got as far as this - http://jsfiddle.net/RuXyP/1/

However, I'm struggling to work out how to add an outline to the arrow bit.
I can't use a border as that's how the arrow is created
I can't use outline as it can't be specified for individual sides

Is there any way for this to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a pseudo element and absolute position:

*The idea is to stack both pseudo:before and after on top of eachother, and draw one that is 1pixel larger on each sides. Set the biggest underneath to draw the red border-color .*

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RuXyP/3/)**

```
    .tag {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 14px;
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #2e353d;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #FF00FF;
    border-right: none;
}
.tag:after, .tag:before {
    content:'';
    margin-right:-10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:100%;
    border-top: 9px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid #2e353d;
}
.tag:before {
    top:-1px;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 9px solid #FF00FF;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly on an @2x display. The arrow head is not positioned correctly.

Comment: I found it was out a bit too. I assumed that was just a small sizing problem and worked when I changed it to this - http://jsfiddle.net/RuXyP/5/
Does it look different on different screen sizes or should this always work?

Comment: Ye just saw that. Thanks so much :) Looks like both this solution and yours below work really well!

Comment: you need to set an height to .tag in order to have the pseudo fit correctly with the correct width for borders , or at least a line-height. From a browser to another , the font properties can be  different(font-family, line-height ) box-sizing can be trigerred too , so you need to look after that too.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to not use pseudo selectors for this, and instead just use two divs for the triangle, one 1px larger than the other, and you simply move the margin over on the second div. Like so:

```
.arrow-border {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1px;
    border-top: 9px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
    border-left: 9px solid #FF00FF;
}

.arrow-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -9px; /* Width of .arrow-border's border */
    margin-top: 2px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent; /* One less than .arrow-border's border width */
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid #2e353d;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RuXyP/4/

Nit: Keep in mind that if you put this in a container smaller than your arrow, it is possible that the arrow head will detach. Generally this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Your demo as an arrow 2 pixel not high enough in my Firefox, that you use 2 tags or 2 pseudo elements , the styling issue are the same, plus , since it is floatting , box and arrow can break appart. Those 2 extra elements should be within .tag in order to keep the arrow in one piece , no matter room is left to draw it

Comment: I am not seeing any issues with my styling on Firefox. Yes, they break apart, but that was how the OP had his structured.

Comment: what i meant was pseudo or tags , style is the same to be applied :) .

Comment: Ah, alright. I'll go ahead and mention the separating issue (which generally shouldn't be a problem unless you are placing it in a very small area)

Comment: Beside there is other methods to draw an arrow , like rotating a square http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/thkib , using images http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/lBpaI and linear gradients can even be used too :)